# Frequent HttpRequestException when talking to Cosmos DB from Web App

Tags: web-services, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

We have a web service (*Azure App Service*) deployed to Azure that talks to our Azure Cosmos DB via the standard C# SDK for Cosmos DB/Document DB.

Both - app service and Cosmos DB account/collections - are in the same resource group and in the same location in Azure.

For certain bulk operations where the web service performs a burst of requests to Cosmos DB we are frequently getting errors in the web service when talking to the database:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[...]

at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.ProxyDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()<---
```

Each of our `ApiController` instances statically allocates a single repository class, which in turn fetches a `IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient` instance in its constructor and holds it for its entire lifetime via

```
  IDocumentDbInitializer dbinit = new DocumentDbInitializer();
  Client = dbinit.GetClient(endpointUrl, myAuthKey, connectionPolicy);
```

So in my understanding we should use only 2 Document DB clients for our 2 repositories in the entire web service.

Things we've tried so far:

- throttle the requests on the client during the bulk operation to less than 3/s
- reduce the clients `ConnectionPolicy.MaxConnectionLimit` from default (50) to 20
- increase the apps `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`

None of these measures significantly reduced the number of exceptions we're experiencing.

Any suggestions how to avoid this error in the first place?
Additional **Cosmos DB SDK** functionality to tune/configure/adapt for our use case..?

Comment: The CosmosDB SDK has indeed retry policies that you configure as part of the `ConnectionPolicy`. These retries happen serversize however so if your call is not async it will lock. I don't know how much this sidetracks you but [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) has built in support for this very thing. The `Range` operations handle all the retry logic for you so you don't get these errors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: You may want to use a Reliable client, IReadWriteReliableClient

Comment: @JoshuaKrstic Using it already, thanks..